# is it possible to detect selfie image in android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have list of images from `MediaStore.images.media`. is it possible to detect selfie images?
I have read about mlkit Selfie Segmentation, but I guess it is about changing the photo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try getting EXIF data from images and compare some parameters.
Add the following dependency to your build.gradle if you wish to utilize ExifInterface:

```
implementation "androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.3"
```

After that you can get EXIF data from photo following next code:

```
Uri gfgUri; // the file uri
InputStream gfgIn;
try {
    gfgIn = getContentResolver().openInputStream(gfgUri);
    ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(gfgIn);
    // Extract the EXIF tag here
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Handle any errors
} finally {
    if (gfgIn != null) {
        try {
            gfgIn.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {}
    }
}
```

You can use, for example, photo resolution for comparing rare and front photos. The resolution often differs: the camera facing the user has a lower resolution than the camera on the back.

A few examples I pulled from [gsmarena.com](https://www.gsmarena.com/compare.php3?idPhone1=10918&idPhone2=11410&idPhone3=11253):

- Google Pixel 6 Pro:      Main: 50 MP; Selfie: 11.1 MP;
- Apple iPhone SE (2022):  Main: 12 MP; Selfie: 7 MP;
- Samsung Galaxy S22 5G:   Main: 50 MP; Selfie: 10 MP;

Comment: what if there is no faces in image?